# Search by date in Google Inbox

Tags: search, inbox-by-gmail

Inbox is an awesome new way of emailing, there is no doubt about that, but lacks a very basic feature (seems so): search by other things than text, like a date.

I tried with Gmail search keywords like `before:12/07/2015` but shows no results.

Is there a way to search emails by date or should I ditch Inbox?

There is a light spec about the search box: 
https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067584, where is not specified nor the keyword `from:` or `in:` which both work. So if a search by date exists, Google is keeping it secret.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tested this in Inbox. The date needs to be in the correct order. Use before:YYYY/MM/DD as documented in the [Advanced Search - Gmail help article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

Comment: But, does it work in Inbox ?

Comment: @TiberiuC. Yes, I thought I mentioned that. Looks like I got carried away paring down my answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: `after:2018/12/24 before:2018/12/26` for example to search for emails **on one day** xmas 2018.